# How to narrow a symbol variable?

Tags: typescript

When having a generic symbol, why doesn't a normal equality narrowing work?

```
declare const sy: unique symbol;
declare const x: symbol;
declare const o: { [sy]: number };

if (x === sy) {
    o[x]; // x is still symbol, therefore this errors
}
```

I'd have expected it to behave similar to any other case, and be narrowed to `typeof sy`.

Comment: Because each `unique symbol` has a completely separate identity, no two `unique symbol` types are assignable or comparable to each other. [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol)

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to compare two unique symbols, because they are always different. It's similar to doing `if (1 === 0)` (produces the same error). However, i am not comparing two unique symbols, i am checking, whether a generic symbol is the same as a given unique symbol.

Comment: `unique symbol` is subset of `symbol` so it should be unique, `unique` only means it should be constant.

Comment: Try `declare const x: typeof sy;` it'll refers to a `unique symbol`, but its identity is tied to `sy`.